# How to use the discord.js giveaway command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The code I have is:

```
C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\src\commands\Testing\GIveaway.js:42
          if (m.reactions.cache.get("�").count <= 1) {
                                         ^
```

That's the error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\src\commands\Testing\GIveaway.js:42:42)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: wouldnt let me post code idk why lol

Comment: Show me your code please. Also you can paste on [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly describes it, `m.reactions.cache.get("�")` is undefined, either way that isn't how you would get the amount of emojis, using `<cache>.get("")` just accesses the collection with the string given

Here's how:

```js
const emoji = m.reactions.cache.find(f => f === "�");
const users = emoji && emoji.users;
const amount = users && users.size;
if(amount && amount <= 1) {
}
```

Comment: not works $ node .
Logged in as Zorek!
C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\src\commands\Testing\GIveaway.js:53
                 users.cache.filter((u) => !u.bot)
                 ^

ReferenceError: users is not defined
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\xdswe\Desktop\Zero\src\commands\Testing\GIveaway.js:53:18)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)

Comment: That's a different issue, but looking at docs part of my code was wrong too, since I thought there would be different instances with the same emoji name instead of just one with `.users` property. Overall just listen to the error message, `users is not defined`, so define it. I'm assuming you would want to do `<Reaction>.users`, I have edited my code for the example.